# LINQ: Creating an IEnumerable<T> from another IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public void DoWork(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        var enumOfX = ?;

        //Other code that uses enumOfX
    }
}
```

How can I create an `IEnumerable<int>` of all the x's?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx):

```
var enumOfX = foos.Select(foo => foo.x);
```

A huge amount of LINQ to Objects is creating one `IEnumerable<T>` from another... the rest is just aggregation :)

Comment: And if you prefer the other syntax: var enumOfX = from foo in foos select foo.x;

Comment: @Dismissile: Yes - I didn't include that here because for queries like that it's pointless to use the query expression form, IMO. Developers really should be comfortable in both :)

Comment: I agree...but some people find the lambda syntax confusing if they are not used to it. Baby steps!

Comment: @Dismissile: Nah, start off with the lambda syntax and *then* explain how query expressions work. Less black magic that way, IMO :)